# Insert newline in Django CharField form

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to know if there is a solution in order to make multiple newlines in my Django Charfield Form.

I have a field `Description` and I would like to write something inside like :

```
Hello,

My name is John.
I am 23 years old.

Is it possible to help me ?
```

Unfortunately, up to now I have :

```
Hello, My name is John. I am 23 years old. Is it possible to help me ?
```

My models looks like :

```
class Ticket(models.Model):

    ...
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Description')
```

[image]

When users are filling Description Field, I would like to set in real-time newlines. As you can see, all strings are in the same line.

How I could do that ?

Comment: Store this data in one line is not a problem, but when users are fillings this field, I would like to set `Caps + Enter` in order to create a newline. And I don't know if it's possible to do that ?

Comment: Yes, but during users are fillings the field ^^ So not exactly in the template, but in my form view. I updated my answer ;)

Comment: Could you set an example ? I have to wrap my textarea like this : `<pre>Hello, <br />my name is John</pre>` inside the CharField ?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. I replaced `models.CharField` by `models.TextArea` :

```
Description = models.TextField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Description')
```

Then in my template, I set :

```
{{value|linebreaks}}
```

And it works ! I can make newlines with `Caps + Enter`

Answer (score 1):

I had a use case where I wanted allow newline characters to be rendered, as well as to restrict the number of characters in the field to a fixed number (Similar to adding a bio field to a profile).
You can combine certain concepts from Templates and Forms to achieve this.

In your model, define the field as a normal `CharField`:

```py
description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

In your form, initialize the field as follows:

```
description = forms.CharField(max_length=250, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':15}))
```

Using the widget as `Textarea` is important here, because if you use the default `TextInput` widget, it will submit the form on pressing Enter, rather than inserting a newline. You can change the size of the Textarea to be rendered by using an `attrs` dict.

Now, finally to display the content correctly with newlines, inside your template, apply the `linebreaks` Django filter:

```
<p>{{ user.profile.description|linebreaks }}</p>
```

The `linebreaks` filter replaces line breaks in plain text with appropriate HTML; a single newline becomes an HTML line break (`<br>`) and a new line followed by a blank line becomes a paragraph break (`</p>`).